# How to configure a dedicated JDK for Apache ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I need to install an MQ server (Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.x) on Linux for our team. I just read some documentation and articles.

Since our Linux server is messy, there may be many JDKs, and the environment variables are not reliable, so I want to specify the JDK path for Artemis (like, put JDK in the Artemis directory), but I haven't searched for a satisfactory solution.

I first did a test installation on my Windows machine. I tried modifying `artemis.cmd` (setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable) and it worked, but I don't think it's a good idea as doing so could be potentially dangerous.

Is there an elegant way to configure JDK for Artemis? Like modifying some Artemis configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `artemis create` command to create an instance of the broker you can either set `JAVA_HOME` in your environment (e.g. `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk`) or you can modify the `artemis` script directly.

Once the instance is created then the proper place to configure `JAVA_HOME` is in `etc/artemis.profile`. Just add a line like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But this can only be configured after the broker is created, right? When using ```apache-artemis-2.27.1/bin/artemis``` to create a broker, I still need to set or change ```JAVA_HOME``` environment variable, because there is no ```etc/artemis.profile``` file in the ```apache-artemis-2.27.1``` directory.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks very much. This has solved my difficulties :)